# Double check with Go's select statement

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang, and after reading [this post](https://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and) on Go's blog, I have the following question.

I start with the following code (from the post):

```
select {
case <-ch:
    // a read from ch has occurred
case <-timeout:
    // the read from ch has timed out
}
```

And based on what [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) states:

> ... It chooses one at random if multiple are ready.

As I understand, it is possible to have my result ready and have a timeout at the same time. My question is whether it is worth it (or correct) to double-check for this inside the default case.

Something like the following:

```
select {
case <-ch:
    // a read from ch has occurred
case <-timeout:
    // the read from ch has timed out

    // So check ch one last time
    select {
    case <-ch:
        // a read from ch has occurred at same time of a timeout,
        // so ignore the timeout
    default:
        // definitive timeout
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, is it? That's a very fine-grained implementation-specific detail that no one can answer on your behalf, especially with no context.

Comment: Every time you check you have the possibly of "just missing" a message, you can't go on forever, Just accept that a message within a few nanoseconds of the timeout might be after the timeout.

Comment: In most cases, no. Only if the result is ready when almost exactly the time runs out can the double check trigger. The time interval between is very slim. And when you use a timeout, it mostly means the result can be discarded if it is too slow and you do not need to be pricise on timing.

Comment: Not to mention, if having a message arrive _exactly_ at `timeout` is valid, then just extend `timeout` slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the channels is a timeout, odds of your work being done and the timeout firing at exactly the same time are so small they make no sense to consider.

The statement "... It chooses one at random if multiple are ready." is applicable when you actually have a viable reason for this to happen - when you have a select case on multiple job channels that you're processing with a single goroutine, for instance.